# Very simple online shop database design

Tags: java, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I need to create a simple database for simple online shop. I crated the following one desing scheme, but I am not sure about correctness of it.
Does it correct?
What are mistakes?

Like here:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/data-model.html

[image]

but I want to add shopping cart

Comment: There is _no such thing_ as a _simple online shop_. Use an off-the-shelf eCommerce package and save everyone TONS of problems down the road.

Comment: I want to create a test project for me. In this small area does this model correct?

Comment: It _looks_ like things are roughly correct, but I would _never ever ever ever ever ever **ever** use_ this in _any_ sort of production environment.

Comment: That said, this isn't really the sort of question that Stack Overflow is designed for, since it's really only beneficial to you, since it depends on your specific DB schema.

Comment: It's only for Java self-education.Can you say does shopping cart connections  correct.What would you improve in it?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one potential issue:

If a `user` has one `shopping_cart`, and a `shopping_cart` has one `user`, should `order` contain both `user_id` and `shopping_cart_id`?

What ensures that these two IDs in this table reference a `user` and `shopping_cart` that are also associated with each other?

EDIT:

I would just get rid of `shopping_cart`, since it only contains totals that you would probably be better off calculating based on the current contents of the order.

Comment: How can I solve it.How need I connect shopping cart to other tables?